# Error: invalid_client no application name

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I am using Google Apps API for my application and trying to authorize it using OAuth2. I have created a project and an application within it using the Google API console. I am using the following URL for authorization:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=(my application clientid)
```

I get the following error,

```
Error: invalid_client
no application name
Request Details
```

I have verified the clientid and even the status of admin SDK.

Comment: they make it so hard for job security. spineless

Answer (score 610, accepted):

That error is displayed in case that under "APIs & auth" -> "Consent screen" you have empty field "PRODUCT NAME" - you need to select e-mail address as well.

You can find "Consent screen" under [a link](https://console.developers.google.com/project)!, click on project name and then go to "APIs & auth" -> "Consent screen".

Comment: Do I need to enable billing, too?

Comment: No, once you add the product name it will work. That's all I had to do.

Comment: i'm using Xcode 4.2 and developer for iOS 7! I have to add the address too!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Be sure to add select your email address too — also on the consent screen. Otherwise you will get another error message.

Comment: I had to re-create the OAuth Client ID and Browser Key for it to work after I selected my e-mail address and filled in a product name.

Comment: for this issue i spent 4 hours, finally fixed using your suggestion Mr.M14d3n and Mr.freebug. Thanks a lot for your suggestion and you saved my time!! keep it up :)

Comment: I just had to wait for changes to apply. About few minutes. No need for re-creating keys.

Comment: I have selected email and PRODUCT NAME, and of course same error.

Comment: Google should do a automated search for the issue using their 'smart api'

Comment: wait for up to 10 minutes for changes to apply.  UPVOTED :)

Answer (score 4):

As @Chris-Kempen says, you have to recreate all necessary OAuth ids **AFTER** you have set the support email for your application.

If you create OAuth credentials **BEFORE** you set the support email address in the consent screen, then it appears that you will always get this error.

Comment: As Matej mentioned later on, it seems that this is just a matter of waiting a bit longer for changes to propagate :)

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar issue, maybe that could help others :

My error was an "invalid client type" instead of "no application name", 
and setting the email and the name of the project did not solve my problem.

However, I had registered my project as a WebApp. When I changed that to "Other", it eventually worked.

Comment: Do you remember where you changed the setting to "Other" instead of WebApp? I can't find it anywhere. :/

Comment: Sorry, I quickly checked and didn't find it anymore, I guess they changed it :/