# CFOAUTH and Adwords

Tags: api, coldfusion, google-ads-api

I am trying to create a script to be able to get report data from adwords using coldfusion 11. I have an api key and everything. I am trying to use CFOAUTH to login but I keep getting the following error: "Invalid client - No application name." Below is the code that i'm using:

```
<cfoauth type="google" clientid="xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" secretkey="xxxxxx" result="r" scope="email" redirecturi="http://localhost/report.cfm">
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect this is the same situation as detailed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677244/error-invalid-client-no-application-name ? Did you google the error message and work through the various documents in the results?

Comment: You're right that worked, thanks!! do you know if there is any good examples on how to use coldfusion to get adwords data?

Comment: I just got a success, but the page says I need to copy this to my application. Not sure what I need to do with this, do you have any idea?   Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:

Comment: I've got no idea sorry. I recommend you ask a new question focusing specifically on that. Having said that, this is all very new to CF11, so it would not surprise me if no-one's really looked at it too much yet.