# CFoauth logging into Google

Tags: api, oauth, coldfusion, google-ads-api

I am trying to write a ColdFusion script that logs into Adwords and I have the following code:

```
<cfoauth type="google" 
         clientid="xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com" 
         secretkey="xxx" 
         result="r" 
         scope="email" 
         redirecturi="http://localhost/report.cfm">
```

When I run the script I get success but then it takes me to page to copy some access token I think. I'm not sure what to do with it after that. Any one use this before and knows what to do?

Comment: Could you share the content that you are receiving after success? If it includes security then just change those fields to similar random text. [Link to your previous question for reference.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24273228/1636917)

Comment: It just takes me to a page that shows the following:   Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: So is it "code" as in HTML code or "code" as in some sort of security string/token?

Comment: its actually a web page, that it goes too.

Comment: its a web page that it goes too, and within the page it just says to copy this really long string into my application