# Getting error on Google+ implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am implementing a Google+ sample app for login. First I create a Client ID like below

[image]

but after all i getting this error when i pressed login button

[image]

Please anybody can help me what i have to do during create the client ID?

Comment: coding is perfect but i think i am creating the client id wrongly.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677244/error-invalid-client-no-application-name

Comment: Welcome :)  @S R Nayak

Comment: go to cloud console again got to the Apis & auths -> consent form add a email address and a product name.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have both product name and an email address set up in Google Apis Console

[image]