# Getting Error after redirecting to iOS app from google plus signin

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Google plus api signin in my iPhone app. Previous i created my app in google plus api using my gmail account. That time its worked good. But, due to some reasons I have added same app in my company account using gmail and I created new project in Google Plus Console and created new Client ID. And in Xcode plist i have changed all new client id which is given by google, but i am getting following error, could anyone have idea about this? IF so, please give your valuable suggestions.

**Received Error Error Domain=com.google.GooglePlusPlatform Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x17da00a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)} and auth object==(null)**

Comment: after spending 4 hours on this issue, finally i fixed my issue. That issue came due to i did not entered details in Consent screen which is an option under API's & Auth. I done simply, Clicked the Consent Screen option and added email in the "Email Adress field" and added Product name in the "Product Name field". Then save clicked. Thats all. I hope this will helps somebody in future. I got this answer from following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677244/error-invalid-client-no-application-name

Comment: Wow, I spent a day on this before finding your answer. Thank you! +100

Comment: @dirkoneill you are welcome and i'm feeling very happy due to my solution helped you!

Comment: You should answer to your question with a read answer and mark it accepted as people will find it easily.

Comment: @DavidAnsermot Okay, i will do that, and thanks for your valuable suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spending 4 hours on this issue, finally i fixed my issue. That issue came due to i did not entered details in Consent screen which is an option under API's & Auth.

I done simply, Clicked the Consent Screen option and added email in the "Email Adress field" and added Product name in the "Product Name field". Then save clicked.

**Thats all. I hope this will helps somebody in future. I got this answer from following link**

[Error: invalid_client no application name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677244/error-invalid-client-no-application-name)