# How can I login to google-plus using google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1 sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, google-plus

I am developing an iPhone application using Google Plus.

When I try to login, I get a 401 error.

I used google-plus-ios-sdk-1.7.1 sdk.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// Override point for customization after application launch.

    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;
    // Read Google+ deep-link data.
    [GPPDeepLink setDelegate:self];
    [GPPDeepLink readDeepLinkAfterInstall];    

    return YES;
}
```

In the `shareviewcontroller`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    GPPSignIn *signIn                   = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser    = YES;
    signIn.scopes                       = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ]; 
    signIn.delegate                     = self;    

    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] trySilentAuthentication];

    _shareConfiguration                 = [ShareConfiguration sharedInstance];
    _shareConfiguration.useNativeSharebox = YES;
    //_shareConfiguration.deepLinkEnabled = YES;
    _shareConfiguration.mediaAttachmentEnabled = YES;
}

-(void)btnGoogleShare_Action
{

    if ([GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication) {
        id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
        [(id<GPPNativeShareBuilder>)shareBuilder attachImage:self.imgView.image];
        [(id<GPPNativeShareBuilder>)shareBuilder setTitle:self.dict[@"title"] description:self.dict[@"comment"] thumbnailURL:nil];
        [shareBuilder open];
    }
    else
    {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

        GPPSignInButton *sign = [[GPPSignInButton alloc] init];

        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {

            appDelegate.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sign to Google +" message:@"After login to Google+, Please retry again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

            [appDelegate.alert setValue:sign forKey:@"accessoryView"]; //works only in iOS7
        } else {

            appDelegate.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sign to Google +" message:@"After login to Google+, Please retry again.\n\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];

            sign.frame = CGRectMake(70, 85, 100, 40);
            [appDelegate.alert addSubview:sign];
        }


        [GPPSignInButton class];
        [appDelegate.alert show];
    }
}
```

Below is a screenshot, can anyone help me?

---

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEv2x.png]

Comment: Try to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677244/error-invalid-client-no-application-name

Comment: I have got success for login, But I have got another error."You cannot attach a link and media to a post at the same time.", How can I share image and text at the same time?

Comment: According to documentation https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/protocol_g_p_p_native_share_builder-p#a9fabcb8ede280d903e1270f58e9928af you can't use 'attachImage' with 'setTitle' function. May be 'setPrefillText' will resolve your issue.

Comment: Really thanks, I have solve all my problem.

Comment: If you solved it according to my comments, then I better post them as an answer and it will be good if you accept it. Otherwise, post your solution for your problem, and accept it, not to leave question without an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it mentioned in the comments, first problem is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677244/error-invalid-client-no-application-name).

Second problem about text and media simultaneously post is mentioned in API documentation for [GPPNativeShareBuilder Protocol Reference](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/protocol_g_p_p_native_share_builder-p#a9fabcb8ede280d903e1270f58e9928af). According to this documentation you can't use `attachImage` with `setTitle` function. Function `setPrefillText` could resolve your issue.